# How to show one page per record, with pagination?

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, pagination

I have an xml file which I am reading into an IEnumerable using linq, now rather than listing every entry using a listbox on one page, id like to show one record on a page.

I've found a blog article on the subject

http://indyfromoz.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/windows-phone-7-listbox-pagination-with-mvvmlight-applicationbar/

But it is using MVVM, how do I go about just loading one record into a form and making it cycle through to records.

Comment: if you are showing just one record on the page, how do you want the users to navigate from one record to the next?

Comment: with the application bar. should i follow the guide and use mvvm? would you recommend it?

Comment: why don't you want to use MVVM? i would recommend that

Comment: thanks i think that's where i'm heading to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use MVVM then you can name your controls and then refer to them by that name in the code behind.

xaml:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myTextblock" />
```

cs:

```
this.myTextblock.Text = myEnumerable.Property;
```